# e-commerce webapp integration via Web Services with MS Dynamics (Navision 2009)

Tags: web-services, integration, microsoft-dynamics, navision

Has anyone tried to build an e-commerce site atop MS Dynamics, using the new Web Services introduced in Nav 2009 ? I'd like to know what kind of load these web services can take, and what kind of resources can be read/written, and any other challenges that I can expect.

I intend to integrate an existing linux-based webapp via Web Services ...

Thanks.

Comment: Good question. I will likely be doing something similar in the next year or two to replace Navision Commerce Portal on Nav 3.7

Comment: Ah, we've been pitched the Commerce Portal as a solution - instead of integrating out existing code. Why are you moving away from it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web services in NAV 2009 can call either CodeUnit or Page objects. Pages allow you to create, read, update and delete rows from their source table. CodeUnits offer greater flexibility, allowing you to invoke any action you can implement in C/AL. I think CodeUnit trigger arguements are limited to primitive types and Records.

NAV web services use Windows Authentication, so your linux app will have to be able to present Windows credentials accordingly. I'm not an expert in this area, so I'm not sure how difficult this is from a Linux machine.

With regard to the supported load, I would ask in the [forum](http://www.mibuso.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=32) at mibuso - this is the largest community of experienced users I am aware of. I expect you will be limited by the CPU and memory of the web service host. NAV does not support clustering\load balancing on the web service tier, but I beleive it is possible to run several side by side.

Comment: -Alex, good answer. I've shared a bit of my experience using nav web services [on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797802/webservice-on-navision-microsoft-dynamics-version-5-or-else): synopsis: VERY easy to expose, tricky to use sometimes.